# UBUNTU 19.10 doesn't detect webcam on my Kogan Atlas 10.1" 2-in-1 D400 Touchscreen Notebook

Tags: 19.04, webcam

I'm a newbie to this forum and to Linux so, please bear with my ignorance.

I have installed UBUNTU 19.10 on my Kogan Atlas 10.1" 2-in-1 D400 Touchscreen Notebook
Intel Atom x5-Z8350 Quad-Core processor
32GB EMMC and 4GB of RAM

It looks good apart from a few  problems I have:

- choppy stuttering Bluethooth sound,
- no touchpad settings,
- no HDMI,
- no touchscreen, and
- my built in webcam is not detected

This is a new laptop which had Windows 10 installed and all working ok but I much prefer to be a bit frustrated in Linux than going back to Windows.

On this topic, I'm looking for help regarding my webcam. Both VLC and cheese didn't detect my webcam.
I had a look around for answers but I had no luck.
Here is some info:

Output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 17ef:6018 Lenovo 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0101:0007  USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 36)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 36)
00:03.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit (rev 36)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 36)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 36)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 36)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 36)
```

(I saw these commands somewhere else so I've repro them here).
Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
Cheers!

Comment: Hi crib!  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  "Cherry Trail" is the version of the Intel chip inside the laptop, not the laptop itself.  Can you please edit your answer to include the make and model of the laptop?  It may help others when searching for the same problem.  Cheers! :-)

Comment: Will do! Thanks, mate!

Comment: FYI.  Your edit still describes the processor rather than the laptop.  Intel don't make laptops.

Comment: @tu-Reinstate Monica-dor duh Done! Thanks